# MySQL PHP order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm writing MySQL query for sort this kind of data

```
Traffic
100/40
12/1
50/20
25/5
```

**the value get by devide right hand side number from left hand side number.**

also i have multi columns for sort

ex - 
`SELECT * FROM fltable ORDER BY Traffic DESC,Speed ASC,Cost ASC`

I need to sort those data **ascending order** and **descending order**, can anyone help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Excuse me, for I have to ponder about this paticular data.

Comment: Are these values stored as `VARCHAR`? Or you want to order them by the result of the dividing?

Comment: ascending order or descending order,yes those are in varchar format

Comment: How do you want to sort them? By the first number before the `/` or by the second number after the `/` or by the result of dividing them? Please edit your question and add these details to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM fractions;
+-----------+
| fractions |
+-----------+
| 100/40    |
| 12/1      |
| 25/5      |
| 50/20     |
+-----------+

SELECT fractions
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(fractions,'/',1)/SUBSTRING_INDEX(fractions,'/',-1)x 
  FROM fractions 
 ORDER 
    BY x DESC;
+-----------+------+
| fractions | x    |
+-----------+------+
| 12/1      |   12 |
| 25/5      |    5 |
| 100/40    |  2.5 |
| 50/20     |  2.5 |
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have multi columns for sort ex - 
SELECT * FROM fltable ORDER BY Traffic DESC,Speed ASC,Cost ASC , do you know how to use this with above query(traffic=fractions), thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like following query:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(SUBSTR(var, 1, POSITION('/' IN var) - 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num 
FROM table 
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Get number before `/` with `SUBSTR` and `CONVERT` to `int`

#### Result with `num` column

```
100
50
25
12
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have multi columns for sort ex - SELECT * FROM fltable ORDER BY Traffic DESC,Speed ASC,Cost ASC , do you know how to use this with above query(traffic=fractions), thanks again.